# Is there performance issues when printing imagens on ZPL format?

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I have a layout with texts in the format ZPL. I'm wondering, is it okay if I replace the whole layout with an image with the text instead? Will printing be slower, or it's the same performance?

Comment: What’s the goal of using an image?

Comment: My layout has many boxes, and when I test in a specific ZPL converter, it seems fine, but when I test in another, some boxes are shifted. So I'm not sure if it will look fine in an actual printer.

Comment: Compare the file sizes of ZPL with text and ZPL with image data.

Comment: If you have access to a network Zebra printer, you can log into the printer remotely via IP address, add the file to the printer's local storage, and it will render the ZPL and return a JPG. I'd trust that over any online rendering tool. As per printing, Raw ZPL would be preferred, its a much smaller amount of data to transfer than an image.

Comment: Excellent, thank you all for the help, I'm going to try this.